# ListBox checkbox command binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I can't figure this out. I thought I had the binding set properly but it's not firing. So I have a View:

```
<ListBox x:Name="EquipmentViewsListBox"
         ItemsSource="{Binding EquipmentViews, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         SelectionMode="Extended"
         BorderThickness="0"
         Height="150"
         Margin="5,5,10,10">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.ViewSelected}" 
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                      Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to fire a command every time the checkbox in that `ListBox` is selected. I created a command on my view model like so:

```
public class SdddViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SdddModel Model { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand<ViewWrapper> ViewSelected { get; set; }

    public SdddViewModel(SdddModel model)
    {
        Model = model;
        ViewSelected = new RelayCommand<ViewWrapper>(OnViewSelected);
    }

    private void OnViewSelected(ViewWrapper obj)
    {
        var asd = obj;
    }
}
```

So I understand that when I do a `ListBox.ItemTemplate` the context for that item becomes the `ListBoxItem` so in my case a class object `ViewWrapper`. That works fine with the `Name` binding for content as well with the `IsSelected` property. It's the command that is not firing when item is checked. I set the relative ancestor to `ListBox` and the `Path=DataContext` but still nothing happens. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `CommandParameter` doesn't match. You Declared it so the `CommandParameter` is `ViewWrapper` but you sent a parameter of type `CheckBox` by using `RelativeSource Self`. Change the `CommandParameter` to simply `{Binding}` which means it sends the `DataContext` of the `ListBoxItem`, which is  `ViewWrapper`.

You could have detected this binding error using [Snoop](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=snoopwpf).

Comment: Dude, you are a genius! So I was at least expecting the stack trace to throw up an exception or something instead it was just doing nothing. I am installing Snoop now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Binding errors don't throw exceptions but you can also see them in the Output window...but yeah, Snoop is a must